# Request for principal permission failed - probably due windows group?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, principalpermission

I googled for this error, didn't find correct answer.. 2 months ago I was doing MVC -> WCF communication. It worked, then I commented out PrincipalPermission attribute to get it working on localhost (VS IIS Express).

After re-enable I receiving error "Request for principal permission failed." I suppose my group is wrong.

WCF side:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Test_Group")]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public int Test()
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        Services.TestClientService testClient = new Services.TestClientService();
        testClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        testClient.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        try
        {
            int response = await testClient.TestAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

WCF web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="authBehavior">
      <!-- serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MyProject.Common.RoleAuthorizationManager, MyProject" -->
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups">
        <authorizationPolicies>
          <add policyType="MyProject.Common.AuthorizationPolicy, MyProject" />
        </authorizationPolicies>
      </serviceAuthorization>
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyProject.Common.IdentityValidator, MyProject" />
        <serviceCertificate findValue="localhost" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" />
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="svcBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyProject.TestService" behaviorConfiguration="authBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding" contract="MyProject.ITestService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<!-- <protocolMapping>
  <add binding="wsDualHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>-->
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Client webconfig:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <customInspector />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="customInspector" type="MyMVC.Services.WCF.Behavior, MyMVC" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/TestService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpEndpointBinding"
    contract="MyMVC.Services.ITestService" name="wsHttpEndpointBinding_ITestService" />
</client>
```

I can't reach WCF AuthorizationPolicy.cs to check if Thread.CurrentPrincipal is set or not.

Any idea how to debug what's wrong? What I think it's problem of Test_Group in windows. WCF and MVC runs in IIS. MVC runs under IIS APPPOOL\MVC which is member of Test_Group.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move PrincipalPermission attribute from class level to method level.

Article: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41c5a8c6-8d17-41c7-9714-4e47296ba75d/principalpermission-attribute-on-class-level-in-wcf-service?forum=wcf (last post mentions it can't be used on class level for WCF :/ )

Answer (score 0):

Is the Test_Group a local group or one in Active Directory? If the latter it should be prefixed with your domain name followed by a back slash. So "Domain\Test_Group"

If not try removing the last attribute and place the following at the start of your function.

```
PrincipalPermission pp = new PrincipalPermission(null, @"Test_Group");
pp.Demand();
```

Comment: Test_Group is local group.

Comment: Only really done permissions group with AD. What authentication do you have enabled for the IIS app?

Comment: Your's code works. Dunno why.. :/ Permissions for MVC: Anonymous only, WCF: Basic + Anonymous

Comment: Oh ASP.NET Impersonation should be enabled on WCF right? Edit: Enabled, still not working :/

Comment: I don't think impersonation is your problem. Can you enable Windows authentication on the WCF app? Also can you disable Anonymous and enable Windows authentication for MVC also? It's strange if you're saying the PP code is working.

Comment: "If you have added yourself to the group and want to test the following code, you must log off the computer and log back on to be included in the group." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-restrict-access-with-the-principalpermissionattribute-class

Comment: Windows authentication enabled on both apps, just I have to keep anonymous for WCF (1 service can be available unathorized). On MVC is enabled only windows auth. No progress :/. Also I did computer reboot, also no progress :(

Comment: Strange is that Thread.CurrentPrincipal is generic principal while HttpContext.Current.User is windows principal (using not attribute method to debug values in Authorization policy)

Comment: WTF! If I move PrincipalPermission attribute from class to method it works. Omg. What's wrong with that?

Comment: That is strange, nothing states that you can't use it on the class. Must be a WCF thing. Glad you sorted it.

Comment: Well Ben I just now found article about it, just it don't explain certainly why. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41c5a8c6-8d17-41c7-9714-4e47296ba75d/principalpermission-attribute-on-class-level-in-wcf-service?forum=wcf last post